# How do I open the extension popup when a user clicks on an element in the active webpage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension and have configured a background script. I want to create an event listener in that script that will listen to click events in the browser. For example, I have a button on the website and If that is clicked, I want the background script to listen to that click event and open a popup

Comment: The standard popup can't be opened programmatically in stable Chrome so you'll have to 1) create a DOM element in the page with your UI e.g. inside an iframe, 2) alternatively show a separate small window created via chrome.windows.create with your UI.

Comment: I fixed the issue. I've answered this question myself.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution. I had to add the below code to my website**

```
// extensionId can be found on the extensions tab

window.chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, {
  data: 'abcd'
});
```

And inside my extension background script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(data => {
  window.open('popup.html', 'extension_popup', 'width=400,height=600,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no');
});
```

I also had to add the below property in my manifest.json so that the extension background script can listen to events from the list of urls in the matches property.

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": [
    "http://localhost:3000/*"
  ]
}
"permissions": [
  ...,
  "http://localhost:3000"
]
```